# Adding one row to p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to add one row(hard coding) in the beginning of both columns. Can someone help me on how to implement it?

I am new to JSF so unable to get it.

```
<p:dataTable var="DataTableValue" value="#{showTableBean.list}">
    <p:column headerText="Attribute" >
        <h:outputText value="#{DataTableValue.attribute}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Vehicle Data">
        <h:outputText value="#{DataTableValue.value}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Why don't you just add that element first in your list inside the backing bean directly

Comment: well... as you can see, the datatable is filled from a list, so why not add a new item to the list and update the datatable? All is plain basic jsf and if you break down your functional problem in small technical ones and solve each one on its own, you'll have a solution in no-time

Comment: Hi,thanks to both of u for your reply.
But actually I have to add Image in one of the rows(specifically 1st row).So what I can do is that I can add the path of image in list but in that case how to use graphicImage tag  to render the image in row??(as I am using outputText tag to get data from  list)